# Report progress for InvokeApiAsync method of Azure Mobile Service in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms app that connects to an Azure Mobile Service API through the "Azure Mobile Service Component".

I have a method that wraps (adds validation, and  some metadata) every call to the Api:

```
azureClient = new MobileServiceClient (
            ApiKeys.MobileServiceUrl,
            ApiKeys.MobileServiceApiKey);

async Task<ResponseT> InvokeApiWrapper<RequestT,ResponseT>(RequestT requestBody, string api)
{
    //validation, metadata, error handlers...

    var response = await azureClient.InvokeApiAsync<RequestT, ResponseT>(api, requestBody, HttpMethod.Post, null);

    //some other validation, metadata, error handlers...
    return response;
}
```

I have send very large pieces of information through this API call (non-negociable requirement) and I would like to report the upload progress with more than an ActivityIndicator.

For example, is it possible to do something like [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/networking/download_progress/), but reporting the InvokeApiAsync progress instead of the progress of downloading something from an URL? How?